# Globally override package virtualbox guest additions (even in NixOS modules)

Tags: nix, nixos

Adding `virtualisation.virtualbox.guest.enable = true;` to the `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` adds the VirtualBox Guest Additions to the resulting NixOS system, and creates a systemd service to run the `VBoxService` executable.

**I want to use a different version of the guest additions than the one which "ships" with the current channel / nixpkgs.**

So I tried to overwrite the package in `configuration.nix` using `nixpkgs.config.packageOverwrites`:

```hs
  nixpkgs = {
    config = {
      allowUnfree = true;
      packageOverrides = xpkgs: {
        linuxPackages = xpkgs.linuxPackages // 
        (
          let vbox = xpkgs.callPackage ./vbox-guest.nix { kernel = xpkgs.linuxPackages.kernel; };
          in
          {
            virtualboxGuestAdditions = vbox;
            kernel = xpkgs.linuxPackages.kernel // {virtualboxGuestAdditions = vbox;};
          }
        );
      };
    };

  };
```

This builds the new Guest Additions package, but does not use it in any way (`nix-store --query --referrers /nix/store/NEW-VBOX-GUEST-ADDS-PATH` shows no referrers); the "shipped" version is still used by both the systemd service as well as the environment packages.

Even providing the "overwrite" directly when selecting the `boot.kernelPackages` does not work:

```hs
boot.kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages // 
        (
          let vbox = pkgs.callPackage ./vbox-guest.nix { kernel = pkgs.linuxPackages.kernel; };
          in
          {
            virtualboxGuestAdditions = vbox;
            kernel = pkgs.linuxPackages.kernel // {virtualboxGuestAdditions = vbox;};
          }
        );
```

Putting the overwrite into `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` or `/root/.nixpkgs/config.nix` doesn't help either.

**How can I change which package is used without manually "rewriting" the nixos module which provides this `...guest.enable` setting?**

Comment: On a related note: Overlays don't work either.

Comment: You have to make an overlay for the kernel with the version you want and then set `boot.kernelPackages` to that version.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for your comment! Isn't that what I'm doing in the last code block? (Setting kernelPackages to my modified attribute set)

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Unfortunately, you can't just merge attribute sets to override packages. You need something like this: https://termbin.com/7nk4 (link expires in a few days, completely untested).  I'm assuming that `vbox-guest.nix` is based on the original derivation and takes the same arguments.